# Possible conflicts when performing an update with WHERE IS NULL and LIMIT?

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I have the following table:

```
| id | claimed |
----------------
| 1  | NULL    |
| 2  | NULL    |
| 3  | NULL    |
```

I can execute this query to update exactly (any) one of the rows without having to execute a select first.

`UPDATE mytable SET claimed = [someId] WHERE claimed IS NULL LIMIT 1`

However, what happens if two concurrent requests of this query take place. Is it possible for the later request to override the value of the first request? I know the chance of this happening is very slight, but still.

Comment: The last value you put in the database being the value which sticks is what's supposed to happen.

Comment: Yes. But in this case it's `WHERE claimed IS NULL` as opposed to for example `WHERE id = 3`. Would it try to update the same row?

Comment: `UPDATE` operations are atomic so in a properly implemented DBMS that should not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing statement `UPDATE mytable SET claimed = [someId] WHERE claimed IS NULL LIMIT 1` in a transaction `t1` locks the respective record and prevents any other transaction `t2` from updating the same record until transaction `t1` commits (or aborts). Transaction `t2` is blocked in the meanwhile; `t2` continues once `t1` commits (or aborts), or `t2` gets aborted automatically once a timeout is reached.

Confer [mysql reference on internal locking methods - row level locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-locking.html):

> MySQL uses row-level locking for InnoDB tables to support simultaneous
>   write access by multiple sessions, making them suitable for
>   multi-user, highly concurrent, and OLTP applications.

and [mysql reference on Locks Set by Different SQL Statements in InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html):

> UPDATE ... WHERE ... sets an exclusive next-key lock on every record
>   the search encounters. However, only an index record lock is required
>   for statements that lock rows using a unique index to search for a
>   unique row.

and finally the behaviour of locking in mysql reference InnoDB Locking for record locks:

> If a transaction T1 holds an exclusive (X) lock on row r, a request
>   from some distinct transaction T2 for a lock of either type on r
>   cannot be granted immediately. Instead, transaction T2 has to wait for
>   transaction T1 to release its lock on row r.

So two queries will not grab the same record as long as these two queries run in different transactions.

Note that the complete record is locked, such that other update operations by other transactions are blocked, even if they would update other attributes of the respective record.

I tried it out using SequelPro, and you can try it out with any client you want, as follows:

1. Make sure that mytable contains at least two records with `claimed
   is null`.
2. Open two connection windows / terminals; let's call them `c1` and
   `c2`.
3. in `c1`, execute the following two commands: `start transaction;
   UPDATE mytable SET claimed = 15 WHERE claimed IS NULL LIMIT 1; #
   No commit so far!`
4. in `c2`, execute similar commands (Note the different value for
   `claimed`): `start transaction; UPDATE mytable SET claimed = 16 WHERE claimed IS NULL LIMIT 1; # Again, no commit so far`
5. Window `c2` should inform you that it is working (i.e. waiting for
   the query to finish).
6. Switch to window `c1` and execute command `commit;`
7. Switch to window `c2`, where the (previously started) query should
   now have been finished; Execute `commit`;
8. When looking into `mytable`, one record should now have `claim=15`,
   and another one should have `claim=16`.